# How can I use mitmproxy to reply form submissions on localhost?

Tags: proxy

I'm working on a web application on localhost. It requires some manual testing, including form submissions. Everything is done via plain HTTP, not HTTPS.

I'd like to use `mitmproxy` or `mitmdump` to record and replay my form submissions. I don't want to proxy all web traffic, just requests to, say, `localhost:3000`.

Ideally, I'd start the proxy on `localhost:8080`, request `localhost:8080` with my browser, and have it relay that request to `localhost:3000`. But another workflow could be fine.

**How can I record and replay form submissions to localhost using `mitmproxy` or `mitmdump`?**

Answer (score 4):

Mitmproxy 4 has gone a different direction in terms of expected use. Previously, I would simply use it to start up a logging reverse proxy, but lately, the development has been towards installing mitmproxy as a system proxy and then listening to the flows from your system (including https traffic) and then filtering your flows to what you wanted.

Though, I have not been able to proxy or see localhost traffic in proxy mode, luckily, the reverse proxy mode still works (even though the documentation is hard to find/understand):

```
mitmproxy --mode reverse:http://localhost:3000/ -p 8080  --set keep_host_header=true
```

This listens in reverse mode, and will contact `http://localhost:3000` as an upstream when your browser goes to `http://localhost:8080/`. When using domains, it's important to send the host header too (usually this is the next question when I hear this one asked).

Now, all you have to do is hit your `http://localhost:8080` and you should see flows.

If you replace `mitmproxy` with `mitmweb` then the webui will be used instead of the terminal ui.

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally, I'd start the proxy on localhost:8080, request localhost:8080 with my browser, and have it relay that request to localhost:3000

You can do so by running mitmproxy in reverse proxy mode: http://mitmproxy.org/doc/modes.html

You can record HTTP requests by specifiying `-w outfile` or by saving flows manually in the mitmproxy UI (`w` keyboard shortcut).

You can replay requests in the mitmproxy UI by pressing `r` or automatically by replaying a saved conversation from the previous step:  http://mitmproxy.org/doc/features/clientreplay.html